# Extract entire elements from large XML to individual files

Tags: bash, shell, sed, scripting

I am looking to extract elements from a large XML file to individual files preferably with a command or script.

The issue is that the XML is not properly formed and is proprietary and whenever I try to use XML utilities like twig or xmlstarlet the data gets munged improperly and special characters get messed up.  Hence my need for a simply regex match and direct copy of exactly what matches to a file (iteratively) for each match where the file names iterate to say match1.xml match2.xml

Example XML source:

```
...
  <testcase id="001" kind="bvt">
    <inputs>
      <arg1>4</arg1>
      <arg2>7</arg2>
    </inputs>
    <expected>11.00</expected>
  </testcase>
  <testcase id="002" kind="drt">
    <inputs>
      <arg1>9</arg1>
      <arg2>6</arg2>
    </inputs>
    <expected>15.00</expected>
  </testcase>
  <testcase id="003" kind="bvt">
    <inputs>
      <arg1>5</arg1>
      <arg2>8</arg2>
    </inputs>
    <expected>13.00</expected>
  </testcase>
...
```

Desired output:
Content of match1.xml:

```
...
  <testcase id="001" kind="bvt">
    <inputs>
      <arg1>4</arg1>
      <arg2>7</arg2>
    </inputs>
    <expected>11.00</expected>
  </testcase>
...
```

Content of match2.xml:

```
..
  <testcase id="002" kind="drt">
    <inputs>
      <arg1>9</arg1>
      <arg2>6</arg2>
    </inputs>
    <expected>15.00</expected>
  </testcase>
...
```

and so on.

Here is some regex I put together that will work.  All I need is an assist on putting together a loop in a bash script to copy each match / element to its own file.

```
(<testcase*[\s\S]*?<\/testcase>)
```

Comment: Most people here probably would discourage using shell/syntactic/regex tools for xml problems - get familiar with xslt and use e.g. [xalan](https://xalan.apache.org/xalan-j/) which has an extension to write out different files during a transform (other processors might have something like it too). If you are sure that your xml always comes in the same formatting then I think it could be done with gawk. - We always appreciate to see code that you try but does have problems still

Comment: The XML is in a proprietary format that is not well formed so I am pretty sure I will have to use something with sed and regex to simply make a greedy capture of entire namespaces and copy each off to an individual file.  The problem I keep running into using utilities like twig and xmlstarlett is that the data gets munged.  Here are some snippets of concessions I have had to make when using utilities.

Comment: for i in *.xml; do sed -i 's/\&amp;/\&/g' $i; done

for i in *.xml; do sed -i 's/\&amp\;quot/\&quot/g' $i; done

for i in *.xml; do sed -i 's/SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string\[1\]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array"/xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string\[1\]"/g' $i; done

for i in *.xml; do sed -i 's/xml:space="preserve" xsi:type="xsd:string"/xsi:type="xsd:string" xml:space="preserve"/g' $i; done

for i in *.xml; do sed -i 's/xml:space="preserve" xsi:type="cm:guid"/xsi:type="cm:guid" xml:space="preserve"/g' $i; done

for i in *.xml; do sed -i 's/Â//g' $1; done

Comment: Here is some regex I put together that will work I am hoping in a sed command that I ultimately would like to incorporate into a bash script to copy each element to its own file.

(<testcase*[\s\S]*?<\/testcase>)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!  Python has a great regex module "re" that I used to solve this.

Below is the python I used.  In this case the element was  everything (including line breaks carriage returns, line feeds special characters etc.) until  and includes the element tag (as needed in this use case).

Every object element gets incrementally written to it's own package-0000 - package-nnnn file and the content is exactly what was in the original file (no munging issues)! :)

```
import re

from re import match
pattern = re.compile(r'(<object>[\s\S]*?<\/object>)', flags=re.S)
with open("/temp/Test/package1.xml", 'r') as f:
    matches = pattern.findall(f.read())

for i, match in enumerate(matches):
    with open("/temp/Test/package-{0:04d}.xml".format(i), 'w') as nf:
        nf.write(match)
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't use shell, so it is not exactly what you asked

Answer (score 3):

Using xmllint to do the parsing (assuming your xml is in a.xml file and main node is named testcases):

```
for num in `cat a.xml | xmllint --xpath '/testcases/testcase/@id' - | sed -r 's/[^"]+"([0-9]+)"/\1 /g'`; do
    cat a.xml | xmllint --xpath "/testcases/testcase[@id=$num]" - > $num.xml;
done
```

First we get the testcase ids (xpath returns them in form of `id="001"` so `sed` is used to retrieve just the numbers).
Then xpath to retrieve just the testcase with appropriate id and saving it to the file with the id name.

Comment: The same can be done with the `xmlstartlet sel` tool.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually a short code piece to write and test... here it is, combining xpath and vtd-xml.

```
import com.ximpleware.*;
import java.io.*;

public class simpleSplit {
    public static void main(String[] s) throws VTDException,IOException{
        VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
        if (!vg.parseFile("d:\\xml\\inputTest.xml", false)) //namespace awareness disabled
            return;
        VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
        AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
        AutoPilot ap2 = new AutoPilot(vn);
        ap.selectXPath("/root/testcase"); // main xpath expression
        ap2.selectXPath("@id");
        byte[] head = "<root>".getBytes();
        byte[] tail = "</root>".getBytes();
        int i=0;
        while((i=ap.evalXPath())!=-1){
            String fileName = ap2.evalXPathToString();
            FileOutputStream fios = new FileOutputStream("d:\\xml\\"+fileName+".xml");
            long l = vn.getElementFragment();
            fios.write(head);
            fios.write(vn.getXML().getBytes(), (int)l, (int)(l>>32));
            fios.write(tail);
            fios.close();
        }
    }
}
```